# Evaluation of a complex circle contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, parametrization

Consider an open circle $\mathcal{C}$ in the complex plane, which is centered on point $1$ of the radius $\varepsilon$ and doesn't intersect with $1-\varepsilon$  oriented in the anti-clockwise
direction. Furthermore we define $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$
$$f(z) = \cfrac{\log(z-1)}{z^2}\,x^z,$$
where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

**Question: What is the exact value of** $\int_\mathcal{C}f$ **?**

Parameterization isn't helpful, because the integral does not tend to zero.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3871198). A parametrization is not necessary, consider what the ML inequality gives for the integral over a small circle around $1$ and how it's different from taking a small circle around $0$.

Comment: Is there a possibility that you could say how u would evaluate this contour? U don't have to be very rigorous, just show me please the "main steps". That would be very nice and helpful!

Comment: The Wikipedia example from the linked question already has the details. You get $O(|\epsilon \ln \epsilon|)$ for the integral over a circle around $1$ and $O(|\epsilon^{-1} \ln \epsilon|)$ for the integral over a circle around $0$. So the first one is negligible, but we can't say anything about the second one. In fact, what you would get from this approach is an integral over $(-\infty, -\epsilon] \cup [\epsilon, 1]$, which doesn't have a finite limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, plus an integral over the part of the contour inside $|z| < \epsilon$, which doesn't have a finite limit either.